# gtm.js and analytics.js are not loading with every page load

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Since evening of last Wednesday (March 15, 2017) I have noticed that the google analytics script is not being requested by my website consistently. When the script does load, the tags are not firing - for example for button clicks.

Is anyone else having this issue? I have searched around for threads regarding any malfunction on Google's side and could not find any. Google recently had an issue with their captcha which is why I am thinking this is an issue on their side.

To note, the site is built on a CMS and the tag manager code snippet is inherited on every page. This snippet has not been altered in the time surrounding March 15th.

Edit: Moving the code snippet from head to body creates consistent behaviour - gtm.js and analytics.js are loading and the tags are firing and registering in GA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for not using dataLayer = [{...}] declaration after script part of container snippet in your pages code. This declaration should be used only before container snippet.

Comment: This turned out to be the issue. I separated the tag putting the script in the head and noscript in the body. When that didn't work I followed your suggestion with moving the script for the dataLayer initialization to be above the script tag for gtm in the head. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check, which you may have already done, is the position of the two code snippets used for implementation. I always position the `<script>` tag first in the `<head>`. Also, make sure the `<noscript>` tag is the first tag rendered in the `<body>`.

I had a similar issue once. My tags would inconsistently fire. After checking the console log, I found that JQuery was being declared toward the bottom of the `<body>`. When I moved the JQuery tag to the `<head>`, the issue was resolved. I can't imagine that you're issue is related, because my issue was due to a mistake by a developer. Nonetheless, check your console log to see if you notice any errors. It may help you determine the root of the problem.

One other thing to try is the [Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) Chrome extension. Run it on your website, and it will run checks on your implementation.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I tried this and I was still getting inconsistent script loading issues and tags not firing.